# scraping product title and url with axios

Tags: express, axios, cheerio

This is code I got from a youtube tutorial originally for scraping news from news site.

```
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const app = express()


const categories = [
    {
        name: 'jamtangan',
        address: 'https://www.blibli.com/c/2/aksesoris-jam-tangan/AK-1000005/JA-1000225',
        base: ''
    }
]

const products = []

categories.forEach(category => {
    axios.get(category.address)
        .then(response => {
            const html = response.data
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)

            $('a:contains("jam")', html).each(function () {
                const title = $(this).text()
                const url = $(this).attr('href')

                products.push({
                    title,
                    url: category.base + url,
                    source: category.name
                })
            })

        })
})




app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('Welcome to my Climate Change News API')
})

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    res.json(products)
})
```

How do I modify this get request so I can get a list of product names and it's url which contain the string "jam" from url listed in **categories** :

```
<div data-v-016547a4="" tabindex="0" class="product__item"><a data-v-016547a4="" href="/p/baterai-maxell-lr44-baterai-kancing-maxel-jam-cts-99-kf909b-kalkulator/ps--LUO-70001-00038?ds=LUO-70001-00038-00001&amp;source=CATEGORY&amp;sid=cf162d5637763f56&amp;cnc=false&amp;pickupPointCode=PP-3137527&amp;pid=LUO-70001-00038" class="" target="_blank"><div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__item-container"><div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__image"><div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__tags"><div data-v-016547a4=""><!----></div></div> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__wishlist"><i data-v-016547a4="" class="bli-wishlist-icon"></i></div> <div data-v-016547a4="" id="PRODUCT_IMAGE_LUO-70001-00038" class="product__image-color product__image-color__gridview"><div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__itemImage product__image__grid-view"><img data-v-016547a4="" title="Baterai Maxell LR44 baterai kancing Maxel jam CTS-99 KF909B kalkulator" src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/medium//97/MTA-7927225/maxell_baterai_maxell_lr44_baterai_kancing_maxel_jam_cts-99_kf909b_kalkulator_full01_qrfnk13y.jpg" alt="Baterai Maxell LR44 baterai kancing Maxel jam CTS-99 KF909B kalkulator"></div> <!----> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__color"><div data-v-2ecbe0a1="" data-v-016547a4="" class="attribute"><!----> <!----></div></div></div> <!----></div> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__description"><div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__content"><!----> <!----> <div data-v-016547a4="" title="Baterai Maxell LR44 baterai kancing Maxel jam CTS-99 KF909B kalkulator" class="product__title">
            Baterai Maxell LR44 baterai kancing Maxel jam CTS-99 KF909B kalkulator
        </div> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body"><p data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__price"><strong data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__price__display">
              Rp1.500
              <!----></strong> <span data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__price__discount"><span data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__price__slashed">Rp5.000</span> <span data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__price__slashed-percentage">
                  70%
                </span></span></p> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__location_container"><!----> <img data-v-016547a4="" src="https://www.static-src.com//siva/asset//11_2020/icon-top-rated-bronze.png" alt="Bronze" class="product__body__location_merchantIcon"> <span data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__location"><!----> <span data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__location__text">
                Kab. Tangerang
              </span></span></div> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__rating"><div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__rating__stars seperator"><img data-v-016547a4="" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNiIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDE2IDE2Ij4KICAgIDxnIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0iZXZlbm9kZCI+CiAgICAgICAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTAgMEgxNlYxNkgweiIvPgogICAgICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNGREI4MTMiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0ibm9uemVybyIgZD0iTTguOTM1IDEuNjQ5bDEuMjYxIDIuNjU5Yy4yMS40Mi42My43IDEuMDUxLjg0bDIuODAzLjQyYy45MS4wNyAxLjI2IDEuMjYuNjMgMS44ODlsLTIuMDMyIDIuMWMtLjM1LjM1LS40Mi44NC0uNDIgMS4yNmwuNDIgMi44NjhjLjIxLjkxLS43NyAxLjYxLTEuNjExIDEuMTlsLTIuNTIzLTEuMzNjLS40Mi0uMjEtLjkxLS4yMS0xLjMzIDBsLTIuNTIzIDEuMzNjLS43Ny40Mi0xLjc1Mi0uMjgtMS42MTItMS4xOWwuNDktMi44NjljLjA3LS40Mi0uMDctLjkxLS40Mi0xLjI2TDEuMzY4IDcuMzg3Yy0uNzAxLS42My0uMzUtMS43NS42My0xLjg5bDIuODAzLS40MmMuMzUtLjE0Ljg0LS40Mi45OC0uOTFMNy4wNDQgMS41MWMuMzUtLjcgMS41NDItLjcgMS44OTIuMTR6Ii8+CiAgICA8L2c+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=" alt="rating icon" class="product__body__rating__stars__icon"> <span data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__rating__stars__rating">4.3</span> <span data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__rating__stars__count">(13)</span></div> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__rating__sold"><span data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__rating__sold__count">Terjual 363</span></div></div> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__rating__badge-gridView"><!----> <!----></div></div></div> <!----></div></div></a> <div data-v-016547a4="" class="product__add-to-cart-section"><button data-v-016547a4="" class="product__body__button">Tambah ke Bag</button></div> <!----></div>
```

Comment: the site is not serverside rendered, so what axios scrapes and cheerio parse is not the dom you see in dev tools, if you look in network tab your find calls to the backend which return json, just use that

Answer (score 0):

```
const tutorial = "Great tutorial from Ania Kubow";
const products = []
const url = category.adress

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('Welcome to Products API')
})

app.get("/prodcuts", async function(req, res) {res.send(
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            const html = response.data
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)

            $('a:contains("jam")', html).each(function () {
                const title = $(this).find("product__title").text()
                const price = $(this).
                find("product__body__price__display").text()

                products.push({
                    title,
                    price,
                })
                console.log(products)
                console.log(tutorial)
            })
  });
        return {status: 200}, {products}
    }).catch((err) => ({status: 500})),
    )
    .json(products)
    .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8")
});
```

You may confirm const url variable value and make sure to no need to apply  trim() or split('n/) methods to clean you data results from text().